# Text to long for sql column

Tags: mysql

I am creating a blog application, The issue I am facing is when I enter in more than 255 in the table column on varchar it throws a error. Since that is the max. Most blog posts are going to be in the 1000 word length so what would be the solution to correct this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html suggests that you might want to use a `MEDIUMTEXT` or `LONGTEXT` type instead of varchar.